# Escaping underline in telegram api when parse_mode = Markdown

Tags: telegram, php-telegram-bot

How can I send this text correctly:

```
$parameters['text'] = 'you must see [example](example.com) or contact with @exmaple_com';
```

if I don't use "Markdown", telegram don't show the above link
if I use "Markdown", telegram can't handle underline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you should use backslash scapes to do so:

```
$parameters['text'] = 'you must see [example](example.com) or contact with @exmaple\\_com';
```

Comment: What can I do if input string is changing to:
`$parameters['text'] = 'you must see [example](example.com) or contact with _@exmaple_com_'`

@example_com <- want in italic formating

Comment: @MaximTronenko Have you solved your problem? Cursive string with underline inside?

Comment: @parsecer It's only using HTML parse_mode:  '<i>@example_com</i>' ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

When you set your parse_mode on Markdown or MarkdownV2, you can't use these characters directly:
`()._-`

You should escape them using backslash,

Also, you should escape backslash itself.
for example, in Golang I wrote this function to solve my problem:

```golang
func FmtTelegram(input string) string {
  return strings.NewReplacer(
    "(", "\\(", // ()_-. are reserved by telegram.
    ")", "\\)",
    "_", "\\_",
    ".", "\\.",
    "-", "\\-",
  ).Replace(input)
}
```

And in PHP you should escape like this:

```php
$parameters['text'] = '\\_com';
# or
$parameters['text'] = '\\.com';
# or
$parameters['text'] = '\\-com';
# or
$parameters['text'] = '\\(com\\)';
```